# connection.confirmTransaction() doesn't wait for confirmation

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, metaplex, metaplex-js, freeze-token-account

I am trying to freeze an NFT with the Metaplex SDK. It all goes well and fine and waits for the transaction to be confirmed, then ends the function. I don't know what happened but now it's not waiting for the transaction to finish (I know this because when I try and fetch the NFT first, it doesn't show it's frozen, but if I wait a little longer it shows that it is).

Here is the code:

```
const lockTransaction = createFreezeDelegatedAccountInstruction({
  //@ts-ignore
  delegate: this.publicKey,
  mint: address,
  edition,
  tokenAccount: nftTokenAcc,
});

//sending the transaction

const transaction = new Transaction().add(lockTransaction);
let { blockhash } = await this.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
//@ts-ignore
transaction.feePayer = this.publicKey;

//@ts-ignore
const signedTransaction = await this.wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
const transactionAddress = await this.connection.sendRawTransaction(
  signedTransaction.serialize()
);

const trasnactionConfirm = await this.connection.confirmTransaction(
  transactionAddress
);
// console.log(trasnactionConfirm);

return transactionAddress;
```

Comment: Thanks for the question! Do any errors appear on your console when this code runs? What version of `@solana/web3.js` are you using? Is the code you pasted into the question part of a function, or does it all live at the top level of a script?

Comment: @steveluscher Hey! So, no errors appear when I run the code or anything, it all works perfectly fine. Just that when the function is finished, it isn't portrayed on the chain for a good 10 seconds, so I can't properly run the next function. And yeah this is all in a function. The version of `@solana/web3.js` is `"^1.66.2"`. Thanks :)

Comment: Change commitment to processed

Comment: @vicyyn I tried "processed" and "confirmed" and none really have an effect. I'm testing this by re-fetching the token account to see if frozen right after the transaction goes through and it doesn't change after like a good 5-ish seconds.